# Aronszajn-Gagliardo Theorem: case of exponent $\theta$ (Exercise 2.8.4 from Bergh-Löfström)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, interpolation-theory

I posted this question on MathOverflow but didn't get any answers, so I'm trying here .

I'm working on the book "Interpolation Spaces" by Bergh and Löfström. I'm interested in solving the exercise 2.8.4 on page 33. which asks:

> Let $A$ be an interpolation space of exponent $\theta$ with respect to $\overline{A}$. Prove that there is a minimal interpolation functor $F_\theta$, which is exact and of exponent $\theta$, such that $F_\theta(\overline{A})=A$.

The following hint is given:

> Use the fonctional $N_\theta(x)=\sum_j\|T_j\|_{A_0,X_0}^{1-\theta}\|T_j\|_{A_1,X_1}^{\theta}\|a_j\|_A$.

The idea is to rely on the proof of the Aronszajn-Gagliardo theorem (thm 2.5.1 from the Bergh-Löfström), which can be stated as follows

> Consider the category $\mathscr{B}$ of all Banach spaces. Let $A$ be an interpolation space with respect to $\overline{A}$. There is a minimal exact interpolation functor $F_0$ such that $F_0(\overline{A})=A$.

If $\overline{X}=(X_0,X_1)$, $X:=F_0(\overline{X})$ is defined by the set of elements $x\in \Sigma(\overline{X})$ which admit a representation $x=\sum_j T_j a_j$ in $\Sigma(\overline{X})$, where $T_j:\overline{A}\rightarrow \overline{X}$, $a_j\in A$. The norm of $x$ in $X$ is defined as the infimum of $N_X(x)$ over all admissible representations of $x$, where
$$
N_X(x)=\sum_j\max\left(\|T_j\|_{A_0,X_0},\|T_j\|_{A_1,X_1}\right)\|a_j\|_A.
$$
I can prove all the points in the same way by remplacing $N_X$ by $N_\theta$ exept one : the inclusion $F_\theta
(\overline{X})\subset \Sigma(\overline{X})$. Indeed, for the classical case, they do it like this : Let $x=\sum_j T_j a_j\in X$, then
$$
\begin{split}
\|x\|_{\Sigma(\overline{X})}&\leq \sum_j\|T_j a_j\|_{\Sigma(\overline{X})}\\
&\leq \sum_j\inf_{a_j=a_j^{(0)}+a_j^{(1)}}\|T_j\|_{A_0,X_0}\|a_j^{(0)}\|_{A_0}+\|T_j\|_{A_1,X_1}\|a_j^{(1)}\|_{A_1}\\
&\leq \sum_j\max\left(\|T_j\|_{A_0,X_0},\|T_j\|_{A_1,X_1}\right)\|a_j\|_{\Sigma(\overline{A})}\\
&\leq C\sum_j\max\left(\|T_j\|_{A_0,X_0},\|T_j\|_{A_1,X_1}\right)\|a_j\|_{A},
\end{split}
$$
since $A\subset \Sigma(\overline{A})$. Therefore, $\|x\|_{\Sigma(\overline{X})}\leq C\|x\|_{X}$. But now for the $\theta$ case, I can't do the same because I can't prove that
$$
\inf_{a_j=a_j^{(0)}+a_j^{(1)}}\|T_j\|_{A_0,X_0}\|a_j^{(0)}\|_{A_0}+\|T_j\|_{A_1,X_1}\|a_j^{(1)}\|_{A_1}\leq C\|T_j\|_{A_0,X_0}^{1-\theta}\|T_j\|_{A_1,X_1}^{\theta}\|a\|_{\Sigma(\overline{A})},
$$
and I don't even know if it is true (we need $C$ independant of $j$ and of the representation of $x$)

So **my question** is: do you have any idea on how to prove the previous inequality or on how to prove that
$$
F_\theta(\overline{X})\subset \Sigma(\overline{X}),
$$
eventually in another way?

Thanks a lot.